# Rails 3, comments nested resource saving 1 instance 4 times

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, resources, nested

I have a strange problem. I have 2 models **Issue, Comment**. Comments is nested inside Issues so for that I have the create action in comments controller as follows:

```
  def create
    @issue = Issue.find(params[:issue_id])
    @comment = @issue.comments.create!(params[:comment])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
        format.html { redirect_to @comment, notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @comment, status: :created, location: @comment }
        format.js #create.js.erb
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

And my create.js.erb:

```
var new_comment = $("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => @comment))%>").hide();
$('#comments').prepend(new_comment);
$('#comment_<%= @comment.id %>').fadeIn('slow');
$('#new_comment')[0].reset();
```

Issue.rb

```
class Issue < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :category, :description, :title

  has_many :comments
end
```

Comment.rb

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :body, :issue_id
  belongs_to :issue
end
```

routes.rb

```
  resources :comments


  resources :issues do
    resources :comments
  end
```

**Problem:** When I create a comment for which is a form partial residing on views/issues/show.html.erb. The comment gets created 4 times in the db.

I couldn't locate what the problem was and whats causing it. Please help

Answer (score 0):

First, I would **build** the associated comment:

```
@comment = @issue.comments.build(params[:comment])
```

And then I would save the comment instance

```
@comment.save
```

And also check the Javascript, maybe you are having some problems with event bubbling and the event is being triggered twice.

Answer (score 0):

I actually was working on some old Rails version where the js files were put inside the /public/assets and that was the reason for that weird behaviour. I deleted all the files inside the /public/assets folder and the app works fine now.